# Can AutoKeras be used for neural networks of PyTorch

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, automation

I use PyTorch, bauces AllenNLP is built on it and good libraries are for it. But can AutoKeras be used for PyTorch based ML pipelines, or am I required to switch to Keras? Google is quite silent when asked for tutorials for this combination. Maybe PyTorch is lacking automated ML framework?

Comment: Welcome to **Ai**! We discourage posts that simply state a problem out of context, and expect the community to solve it. Assuming you tried to solve it yourself and got stuck, it may be helpful if you wrote your thoughts and what you could not figure out. It will definitely draw more answers to your post. Until then, the question will be voted to be closed / downvoted. You may also want to check out our community guidelines/hints, or use the search engine of this site to find similar questions that were already answered. So lets do something timely scientific.

Answer (score 2):

"Keras is a high-level neural networks API, written in Python and capable of running on top of TensorFlow, CNTK, or Theano."

But I found a useful tool which collects different [deep learning model convertors](https://github.com/ysh329/deep-learning-model-convertor).

Hope this will be useful for you :D